# RCurl, basic authentication with API key

Tags: r, authentication, rcurl

I used to use RCurl, to grab the data that needs login. Now I have to grab the data using api key (as well as userid,password) and it needs a basic authentication (Radian6 api : http://socialcloud.radian6.com/docs/read/Getting_Started)

If it doesn't need an authentication, the code will be something like..

```
getURL("https:// address", userpwd="id:pswd", httpauth = 1L)
```

but I have no idea how to plug in api key for authentication. So far I was able to find examples written in python or Java but haven't found R example yet. Can anyone point me to the right direction? I'm wondering how I can use RCurl for basic authentication and how I can use a token to grab the data. (fyi, this is how python works :[Urllib2 authentication with API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576201/urllib2-authentication-with-api-key))

Any advice will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

You might find it a little easier to use httr. The code would look something like this:

```
library(httr)

req <- GET("https://address.com/authenticate", 
  authenticate("user", "pass", type = "basic"),
  add_headers(auth_appkey = api_key))
stop_for_status(req)
content(req)
# Then extract token etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance! This is my first time using httr. One quick question. Is there any other syntax that I can plug in username and password? With same login credential, I was able to get token using python, but this code kept throwing error message. - "<error>A username and a password request header are both required.</error> "

Comment: @user1486507 there's lots of ways an API might want a username/password. Sounds like it wants something custom in the headers.