# Create new column with matching JSON part

Tags: json, r

I try to extract the matching JSON part from column 'data' into new column 'geo'. This code only extracts the first row correctly, and then repeats itself. I expect the 'geo' column to read:

GEO STOCKHOLM, GEO NEW YORK, GEO MADRID, GEO LONDON

instead of currently

GEO STOCKHOLM, GEO STOCKHOLM, GEO STOCKHOLM, GEO STOCKHOLM

Code:

```
library(rjson)
data <- c('["GEO STOCKHOLM","TYPE LOW"]','["GEO NEW YORK","TYPE MEDIUM"]','["GEO MADRID","TYPE HIGH"]','["GEO LONDON","TYPE MAX"]')
df <- data.frame(data, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$geo <- grep("GEO", fromJSON(df$data), value = TRUE)
```

As you can see, I just want to keep the 'geo' part within semicolons, and lose the 'type' part. Looking at the df dataframe, this is my (incorrect) output:

[Incorrect output df dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o00Ha.jpg)

Comment: could this answer be somehow helpful?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045080/r-read-and-parse-json/40046159#40046159

Comment: See what `fromJSON(df$data)` produces. It just iterates through GEOM STOCKHOLM and TYPE LOW.

Comment: Not really Leonardo, thanks though. The problem seems to be that the grep function does NOT iterate over the df$data columns for some reason? It seems to just extract the first element correctly, then repeat itself.

Comment: Thats the thing Roman, fromJSON(df$data) just gives me the first set like so: [1] "GEO STOCKHOLM" "TYPE LOW". I would expect it to give me all four rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
df$geo <- sapply(sapply(df$data, FUN = fromJSON, simplify = FALSE), FUN = "[", 1)

                            data           geo
1   ["GEO STOCKHOLM","TYPE LOW"] GEO STOCKHOLM
2 ["GEO NEW YORK","TYPE MEDIUM"]  GEO NEW YORK
3     ["GEO MADRID","TYPE HIGH"]    GEO MADRID
4      ["GEO LONDON","TYPE MAX"]    GEO LONDON
```

Comment: Close thanks, but all it does it insert the first of two elements. The order could be different, so it need to recognize whenever the term 'GEO' is present in the element and extract that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I ended up building my own function:

```
getJSON <- function(x) {
result <- grep("GEO", rjson::fromJSON(x), value = TRUE)
return(result)
```

}

And then:

```
df$geo <- sapply(df$data, getJSON)
```

This way I catch all the 'geo' elements, regardless of number of elements or their order. Your input helped me finally get there. Thanks.