# How to authenticate to Icobench.com API with 2 keys in R

Tags: r, api, authentication

I just received a public and private key to connect to ICObench api. I'm quite used to use R, but I admit i found no accurate info on how to authenticate to an API that asks for a public an private key.

[Here is their api page](https://icobench.com/developers#manage_api_access) telling how to authenticate (though not with R).

I tried the following code (using httr package), which i found on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286900/rcurl-basic-authentication-with-api-key) :

```
req <- GET("https://icobench.com/api/v1/icos/ratings",
           authenticate("user@gmail.com" , "password"),
           add_headers(privateKey = privatekey ),
           add_headers(publicKey = publickey))
stop_for_status(req)
content(req
```

)

But this code does not seem to work with 2 keys/2 headers. I get the following error message :

```
"Not provided or missing X-ICObench-Key"
```

Any idea how to authenticate properly to this API ? There's some nice tutorials for the rest :)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd like to help. I made an account but when I click their link to get the API page it just takes me to the settings/profile page.

Comment: I think you have to fill some info on you and why you want to access the API before it's granted to you. They grant it almost automatically though.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following a try

```
signature <- openssl::base64_encode(openssl::sha384("", privateKey))

req <- GET("https://icobench.com/api/v1/icos/ratings",
           authenticate("user@gmail.com" , "password"),
           add_headers("X-ICObench-Sig"=signature),
           add_headers("X-ICObench-Key"=publickey))
stop_for_status(req)
content(req)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) . Unfortunately I get "[1] "Invalid Content Verification Signature"". This is weird, I double checked the private and public keys, and they are good.

Comment: I tried putting our the "-" between the numbers in each key, and then i get this error message :  "Invalid Public Key"